# Getting TypeError: 'int' when iterating trough data for my API

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to iterate trough data from API and send them to my server but I am getting: **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**. Any idea how to solve it ?

Code for data source"

```
response = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
data = response.content
```

Code for iteration (BASE is variable for IP):

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    response = requests.put(BASE + "status/" + str(i), data[i])
    print(response.json())
```

Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restApi/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    response = requests.put(BASE + "status/" + str(i), data[i])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 130, in put
    return request("put", url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 523, in send
    for i in request.body:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please show full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the content directly. You need to parse it before use it:

```
response = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
data = response.json()

for i in range(len(data)):
    response = print("status/" + str(i), data[i])
```

Comment: More context here:- https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content